# Add animation to buttons in android

Tags: android, animation, android-activity, android-imagebutton

So this is the main activity of my app:

[image]

As u can see, there are 6 buttons.

1. I thought about the idea of setting the animation of them to be like when a bubble pops up...i mean whenever the main activity shows up i want the button to "bubble up"+ i don't want them to bubble up all together, i want a Interval of approximately half a second between each button.
2. Another animation i would like to add is the rounding animation, in which, whenever i press a button, it firstly spinning and then i do some actions...

Hopefully guys you understand my willings, i would be glad for any help :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html

Comment: @KushtrimP. thank you, it pretty much what i tried and it works, the problam is that i start the animation in onCreate method which cause the animation a slightly earlier, before the user can even see the animation+whenever i return to this activity there is no animation at all and i want it to be

Comment: Try overriding onWindowFocusChanged()  and starting animation from there

Comment: @KushtrimP. It looks like it solves the problem..thanks. one more thing, as u can see there are 6 button, i want them to animate in different times, one after another, how can i do that?

Comment: Use the startOffset property

Answer (score 0):

u can see android api demo where some example given for button animation

https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCgQFjAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Fgoogledrive%2Fandroid-demos&ei=OL70VKn6PJSpuwTsvoLQDw&usg=AFQjCNEkkqFYd6xmuOzqdv-eXhKitC_o-w&sig2=fUuJK2OQpgLIF6qZCWOY5g&bvm=bv.87269000,d.c2E